# Two processes reading/writing to the same file Python

Tags: python, file-io, process

I have one process who's reading from a file (using `file.read()`) and one process who's writing to the same file (`file.write()`). The problem is it doesn't work - I get no errors but they can't operate at the same time. I've tried making the read and write operations none-blocking and then flushing the stream, as follows:

```
fcntl.fcntl(file, fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
file.write(msg)
file.flush()
```

Am I completely misunderstanding it? How should one accomplish writing and reading to one file from different processes?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

test1.py

```
import os
f = open('txt.txt', 'a', os.O_NONBLOCK)
while 1:
        f.write('asd')
        f.flush()
```

test2.py

```
import os
f = open('txt.txt', 'r', os.O_NONBLOCK)
while 1:
    print f.read(3)
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Note that os.O_NONBLOCK is not available under Windows.

Answer (score 10):

Is there a reason to use a common file? Inter-process communication is probably much easier using [sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example).

Comment: You certainly got a point. I initially thought of this way of doing it, but changed my mind and went for file i/o, and once I encountered the problem and started wrestling with it, I sort of came to the point where I want to solve it :P. Thanks for the answer still.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this *Read-Write Lock* class:

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502283-read-write-lock-class-rlock-like/

and at this articles about locking and threading:

- http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm
- http://linuxgazette.net/107/pai.html

Answer (score 1):

Another great way to do this is to use a pipe

[This example](https://www.python-course.eu/pipes.php) instantiates a pipe, which returns a reader and a writer object. Then one process writes to the pipe using the writer and the other reads from it using the reader.

Python os.pipe(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.pipe