# How do I parse data from log file that updates every second in real time?

Tags: python, parsing, logging, real-time

I am trying to extract numbers from a log file that i get from a serial port using puTTY. The log file updates itself every second and I want to parse the new line of the log file every time it updates itself.

I am doing this on python. Currently I have managed to parse through static log files and save the numbers that I want into a new file but am not sure how to go about having the files to continuously add new data that comes from the updated log.

```
import re
import time
from time import strftime

def main():
    log_file_path = r"/Users/Mookuloo/Downloads/putty.log"
    export_file_path = r"/Users/Mookuloo/Downloads\filtered"

    time_now = str(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", time.localtime()))

    file = "\\" + "Parser Output " + time_now + ".txt"
    export_file = export_file_path + file

    regex ='(SPHB=\d\d\d\D\d)'

    parseData(log_file_path, export_file, regex, read_line=True)



def parseData(log_file_path, export_file, regex, read_line=True):
    with open(log_file_path, "r") as file:
        match_list = []
        if read_line == True:
            for line in file:
                for match in re.finditer(regex, line, re.S):
                    match_text = match.group()
                    match_list.append(match_text)
                    print(match_text)
        else:
            data = file.read()
            for match in re.finditer(regex, data, re.S):
                match_text = match.group();
                match_list.append(match_text)
    file.close

    with open(export_file, "w+") as file:
        file.write("EXPORTED:\n")
        match_list_clean = list(match_list)
        for item in range(0, len(match_list_clean)):
            number= float(match_list_clean[item][5:])
            print (number)
            file.write(str(number) + "\n")
    file.close

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect the new log file to be continuously updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two processes reading/writing to the same file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211292/two-processes-reading-writing-to-the-same-file-python)